# How to write query with LIKE in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11389782c3c3751def6a68"),
    "\"dname\"" : "\"W6PJBu7wC0Demyl86pd8Um5NHk3ukqsdtVA6                       \""
}
```

I've searched a lot and found that I can write it as: `/`. For example, I need to get all document where `dname` **starts** with `c`, for this I do:

```
db.getCollection('flat').find({"\"dname\"" : "\"c/"})
```

Also I've tried this:

```
db.getCollection('flat').find({"\"dname\"" : "/^\"c/"})
```

but it does not work. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regexes

For example, to find records with dname starting with c: `db.getCollection('flat').find({"\"dname\"" : /^\"c/})`